# convert from C# to VBA

Tags: vba

I have a code that wrote with C#.But I need to convert it to VBA and then use from it into GIS.
how can I convert it be VBA?

Comment: ArcGIS 10 will be the last release that supports VBA.  If you plan to migrate/upgrade to ArcGIS 10+ then your VBA code will no longer work.  The recommended approach is to write your application in Python, VB.NET, or C#. Since you already have your application in C# you may want to consider keeping it in C#.  The deprecation document can be found here: http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2010/08/19/important-deprecation-announcement-for-arcgis-10-and-future-release-of-10-1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on how much code you are talking about.  Most people try to go the other way, that is VB6\VBA to c# or vb.net.

But for your case a start might be to convert the methods to VB.net and then clean up the code to VBA.

[C# <-> VB.net translator](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/)

Comment: tanks a lot.I use from this.but I can't find answer after translate.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You could post the code?

Comment: yes.tanks.solved my problem.